# Syncing MAMP PRO 3 databases over Dropbox?

Tags: database, dropbox, mamp-pro

There are [various](http://simonsmith.io/syncing-mamp-databases-with-dropbox/) [articles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Irq-uJA-aaA) on syncing MAMP Pro databases across computers with Dropbox, but none of them seem to work for me on MAMP Pro 3. I can sync site files fine, but servers and databases seem out of reach.

I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite on both desktop and laptop, using MAMP Pro 3 and Dropbox.

Has anybody managed to work this out yet?